# MLFLOW UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec error while logging the model

Tags: python, logging, decode, mlflow

I am trying to log a model with MLflow but each time i get the following warning. The debug mode have been activated to have a more verbose warning.

```
2023/01/09 18:17:50 WARNING mlflow.utils.environment: Encountered an unexpected error while inferring pip requirements (model URI: C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp25zp2aqv\model\model.pkl, flavor: sklearn), fall back to return ['scikit-learn==1.0.2', 'cloudpickle==2.1.0']. Set logging level to DEBUG to see the full traceback.
2023/01/09 18:17:50 DEBUG mlflow.utils.environment: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\_verse\test_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\environment.py", line 378, in infer_pip_requirements
    return _infer_requirements(model_uri, flavor)
  File "D:\_verse\test_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\requirements_utils.py", line 345, in _infer_requirements
    modules = _capture_imported_modules(model_uri, flavor)
  File "D:\_verse\test_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\requirements_utils.py", line 277, in _capture_imported_modules
    json.dumps(sys.path),
  File "D:\_verse\test_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\requirements_utils.py", line 208, in _run_command
    stderr = stderr.decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 472: invalid continuation byte
```

Here is a part of the code :

```
####======= mlflow store =======####
with mlflow.start_run():
    
    print("Elasticnet model (alpha=%f, l1_ratio=%f):" % (alpha, l1_ratio))
    print("  RMSE: %s" % rmse)
    print("  MAE: %s" % mae)
    print("  R2: %s" % r2)
    print("\n")

    # Parameters logging
    for i in model_parameters:
        mlflow.log_param(get_variable_name(i), i)

    # Metrics logging
    for i in model_metrics: 
        mlflow.log_metric(get_variable_name(i), i)
            
    tracking_url_type_store = urlparse(mlflow.get_tracking_uri()).scheme
    
    print(f"URL type store : {tracking_url_type_store}\n")

    # Model registry does not work with file store
    if tracking_url_type_store != "file":
        mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr, "model", registered_model_name="ElasticnetWineModel")
    else:
        mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr, "model")
    
# Users informations
print(f"\nAll the data have been stored there : {mlflow.get_tracking_uri()}")
print("\n========== End of local run ==========")
print("==========   %s seconds   ==========" % round((time.time() - start_time),2))
```

If somebody can give any advices, it would be nice :)

Comment: Which version of Python?  I'd expect `sys.path` to already be Unicode and not require decoding.

Comment: This is python 3.7.12.

The sys.path is in UTF-8

Comment: I'm on Python 3.8.6, and `for x in sys.path: print(type(x))` shows `<class 'str'>` for all, meaning they're Unicode and can't be decoded.